# Side-by-side error when running program with manifest present and from a different computer

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, manifest, regfreecom

I have a VB6 application that uses a pack of VB dlls that were built using the .NET 4.7.2 framework.

Whenever i try to run the application from a different computer, with the application manifest present, i get the "side-by-side configuration incorrect" error. When i say different computer, i mean running the program using a shortcut to a central applications server where the app is located (i.e. \192....\c$\appFolder).

I have tried embedding the manifest into the .exe but to no avail.

Here is my sxstrace file.

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\WMS.exe.Manifest
    AssemblyDirectory = \\192.168.9.9\Run\VB-RX\WMS\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\WMS.exe.Manifest.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is WMS.exe,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Reference: RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: Integracao,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: PNXML,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: RSPrint,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
INFO: Resolving reference RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture ia64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM\RXCOMM.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM\RXCOMM.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.

=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\WMS.exe.Manifest
    AssemblyDirectory = \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\WMS.exe.Manifest.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is WMS.exe,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Reference: RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: Integracao,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: PNXML,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: RSPrint,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0"
INFO: Resolving reference RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture ia64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM\RXCOMM.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at \\192.168.9.9\c$\Run\VB-RX\WMS\RXCOMM\RXCOMM.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference RXCOMM,processorArchitecture="ia64",version="1.0.0.0".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
        name="WMS.exe"
        version="1.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="ia64" />
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    name="RXCOMM"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="ia64" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    name="Integracao"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="ia64" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    name="PNXML"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="ia64" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    name="RSPrint"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="ia64" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>           
</assembly>
```

Comment: It sounds like if you run your EXE from computer A, it works, but when you run from computer B, it fails. If that is the case, the problem is probably configuration of B (a dependency is missing?) For instance, does it have the correct framework version installed?

Comment: Show `RXCOMM` dependent assembly manifest too. It's the one missing according to log.